# Quadratic Character of -3

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I am studying Ireland & Rosen's Number Theory text, and I am asked to find the quadratic character of $-3$ modulo a prime $p$ via the method presented in $6.2$ of the text (in which they find the quadratic character of $2$). Here is my work:

As a start, let $\omega = e^{2\pi i /3}$ be a root of $x^3 - 1$. Let $\tau = 2\omega + 1$. Observe that $(2 \omega + 1)^2 = -3$. Raising both sides to the power $(p-1)/2$, I get

$$
(2 \omega + 1)^{p-1} \equiv (-3)^{(p-1)/2} \equiv \Big{(}\frac{-3}{p}\Big{)} \pmod{p}.
$$

Next, I multiply by $(2 \omega + 1)$ to get

$$
(2 \omega + 1)\Big{(}\frac{-3}{p}\Big{)} \equiv (2 \omega + 1)^p \equiv (2\omega)^p + 1 \equiv 2\omega^{p} + 1\pmod{p}.
$$

From here, I am at a stand-still. At this point in the text for finding the quadratic character of $2$, the authors consider cases for $p$ modulo $8$, but they don't explain this choice. Logically, I thought it wise to consider $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{3}$, which case $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ implies $2\omega^p + 1 = \tau$, and $p \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$ implies $2\omega^p + 1 = -\tau$, but I can't seem to see the horizon still.

I would prefer a nudge, instead of a full answer, as I would like to continue this problem myself.

Comment: $\tau = \omega - \omega^2$.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you were able to use $\tau = 2 \omega + 1$ to get most of the way there.  Recover $(-3)^{(p-1)/2}$ for each case $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $p \equiv -1 \bmod 3$, and you're done.

Comment: When $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, we have $2 \omega^p + 1 = \tau$. Additionally, $(p-1)/2$ must be an integer, so $p \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$. Additionally, when $p \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$, we have $2 \omega^p + 1 = -\tau$, and since $(p-1)/2$ must be an integer, $p \equiv -1 \pmod{6}$. From here, I'm trying to form $\displaystyle\Big{(}\frac{-3}{p}\Big{)} = (-1)^{f}$, where $f = \frac{p^2 - 1}{24}$ or something... But I can't get it to work.

Comment: Since $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{6}$, $p^2 -1 \equiv 0 \pmod{36}$.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm blinded by what's in front of me. The above tells me that $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ implies $\displaystyle\Big{(}\frac{-3}{p}\Big{)} = 1$, since we may divide by $\tau$ in the second series of congruences in my OP. Thus, $\displaystyle\Big{(}\frac{-3}{p}\Big{)} = 1$ if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, and is $-1$ if $p \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$.